# Clickhouse - Materialized view is not updating for Postgres source table

Tags: clickhouse

My requirement is to have a Clickhouse Materialized view based on a Postgres table. A Postgres connection is created in Clickhouse and the table data is visible. Materialized view is not reflecting insert/updated data.

Postgres table

```
CREATE TABLE prod_data (
    id int4 NOT NULL,
    prod_id int4 NOT NULL,
    prod_type int4 NOT NULL,
    prod_cost float4 NULL,
    sell_cost float4 NULL,
    created_by varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    created_date timestamp(6) NOT NULL,
    updated_by varchar(100) NULL,
    updated_date timestamp(6) NULL
);
```

Materialized view in Clickhouse

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW testing.mv_prod_data_summerge
(
    prod_id Int32,
    prod_type Int32,
    prod_cost Nullable(Float32),
    sell_cost Nullable(Float32)
) 
ENGINE = SummingMergeTree
order by (prod_id,prod_type)
populate
AS
SELECT
    prod_id,
    prod_type,
    sum(prod_cost) as prod_cost ,
    sum(sell_cost) as sell_cost
FROM PG_mi_datasource.test_prod_data
group by prod_id ,prod_type ;
```

After creating the Materialized view, the changes made in base table is not reflecting. On execution of the base query the changes are visible. The aggregate function sum and sumState exhibit same behavior.
Kindly suggest what needs to be done to have the changes reflected in Materialized view.

Answer (score 0):

Materiazed View is an insert trigger. They work only if you insert data into ClickHouse tables.

https://den-crane.github.io/Everything_you_should_know_about_materialized_views_commented.pdf

You may use MaterializedPostgreSQL
https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/integrations/postgresql/postgres-with-clickhouse-database-engine/#1-in-postgresql